# Javascript count arrays in array with value

Tags: javascript

I have some problems counting some arrays in my app.
I have some objects that are defined as countries and products, product belongs to country.
And that object looks like:

```
 "data": [
        {
            "id": "1ffaf18c-b7e1-4912-9c10-bbff1b82497e",
            "name": "Italy",
            "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/italy/flag-400.png",
            "active": true,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": "8a09b307-d89e-4dc6-a3ab-b255947d59d4",
                    "type": "product",
                    "active": true,
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "id": "c376e1cb-e383-4c70-b8cc-dc238a1a4e29",
                            "order": null,
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "63866d5d-cddf-4019-8795-5a5913fadc66",
                    "type": "accessory",
                    "active": true,
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "id": "d4f8d7df-39d1-435c-9f0d-2096a68ffdb5",
                            "order": null,
                        }
                    ]
                },
           {
            "id": "1ffaf18c-b7e1-4912-9c10-bbff1b82497e",
            "name": "Spain",
            "flag": "https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/italy/flag-400.png",
            "active": true,
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": "8a09b307-d89e-4dc6-a3ab-b255947d59d4",
                    "type": "product",
                    "active": true,
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "id": "c376e1cb-e383-4c70-b8cc-dc238a1a4e29",
                            "order": null,
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "63866d5d-cddf-4019-8795-5a5913fadc66",
                    "type": "accessory",
                    "active": true,
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "id": "d4f8d7df-39d1-435c-9f0d-2096a68ffdb5",
                            "order": null,
                        }
                    ]
                }
          
]
```

So for selected country I need to count how many products are active, and I have value 'active' in both objects.
I did something like this.

```
countSelectedProducts(index) {
            var i;  
            var occurs = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < this.data[index].products[i].length; i++) {
               if ( 'active' in this.data[index].products[i] && this.data[index].products[i].active === true ) occurs++;
            }

            return occurs;
        },
```

But it return only 0, what could be a problem?

Comment: What should be `data[index].products[i]`? It should be `data[index].products` without `[i]`. I guess it's typo.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

```
countSelectedProducts(index) {
        return this.data[index].products.reduce((counter, { active }) => active === true ? counter += 1 : counter, 0);
    },
```